# Excel VBA Filedialog: Check if .selecteditems(1) is opened by another user

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a Filedialog to select a file, but I need to know if the file is opened.
I have tried using GetAttr but I always get code 32 (File has been changed since last backup)
I have also tried using IsFileOpen from MSDN (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open) but this method always returns my own user when the file is opened by my colleague. IsFileOpen works as expected when the file is closed, as I have tested this when my colleague has closed the file.

How should I proceed for my implementation of IsFileOpen to return the username of my colleague and not my own?

UPDATE 3 and reply to Ricardo Rodrigues:
From the article on MSDN the proposed solutions does not return what I need, I'm afraid...
("The UserStatus property doesn't return information about users who have the specified workbook open as read-only.")
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-userstatus-property-excel)

UPDATE 2 and reply to Tim Williams and Ricardo Rodrigues:
I now see my mistake by using the GetFileOwner procedure... Of course it gives my own username as it was in fact I that created the file...

Ricardo: I will test your procedure and revert back

UPDATE and reply to Tim Williams:

```
Function GetFileOwner(fileDir As String, fileName As String) As String

 'On Error Resume Next
Dim secUtil As Object
Dim secDesc As Object
Set secUtil = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1)
GetFileOwner = secDesc.Owner
```

End Function

Comment: "this method always returns my own user when the file is opened by my colleague" - the code you linked to doesn't return who has the file open, only whether or not it's currently locked.  Are you maybe using a different piece of code?

Comment: I am using the Owner property of the GetSecurityDescriptor of ADsSecutiryUtility:

Comment: That's not the code you linked in your question...

Comment: Anyone who has the file open as read-only may not be detectable: is that what you need to find out?

Comment: @TimWilliams : Yes! :)

Comment: For what purpose?  Like I mentioned, I don't think you can detect who has a file opened as read-only: it doesn't leave a "mark" on the original file.  If you wanted to do something like this you'd need to somehow (e.g.) log every opening of the file (maybe via the workbook_open event) into a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the UserStatus property ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215930%28v=office.11%29.aspx))

> Returns a 1-based, two-dimensional array that provides information
>   about each user who has the workbook open as a shared list. The first
>   element of the second dimension is the name of the user, the second
>   element is the date and time when the user last opened the workbook,
>   and the third element is a number indicating the type of list (1
>   indicates exclusive, and 2 indicates shared). Read-only Variant.

**Example**

This example creates a new workbook and inserts into it information about all users who have the active workbook open as a shared list.

```
users = ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus
With Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
    For row = 1 To UBound(users, 1)
        .Cells(row, 1) = users(row, 1)
        .Cells(row, 2) = users(row, 2)
        Select Case users(row, 3)
            Case 1
                .Cells(row, 3).Value = "Exclusive"
            Case 2
                .Cells(row, 3).Value = "Shared"
        End Select
    Next
End With
```